# DependencyInjection with AutoFac

Tags: c#, autofac

I keep getting an error, saying that there isn't any available constructors for the constructor parameters I have created in class `Service`.

Here's the code:

*Main.cs*

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
        ContainerBuilder containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<Service>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IServiceScopeFactory).Assembly).As<IServiceScopeFactory>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IConfiguration).Assembly).As<IConfiguration>();

        IContainer container = containerBuilder.Build();

        HostFactory.Run(configure =>
        {
            configure.Service<Service>(s =>
            {
                s.ConstructUsing(hostSettings => container.Resolve<Service>());
                s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
                s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
            });
        });
}
```

**Service.cs**:

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Service(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory =   serviceScopeFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceScopeFactory));
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, deleted my previous answer, but preserving your comment:

The error that i keep getting is: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'WindowsService.Service' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceScopeFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration)'

I had a similarish project and added IServiceScopeFactory and managed to reproduce the problem. I also believe found the fix for it. So try this please:

```cs
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContainerBuilder containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<Service>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
 containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IServiceScopeFactory).Assembly).As<IServiceScopeFactory>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IConfiguration).Assembly).As<IConfiguration>();

           // Add these
           var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
           containerBuilder.Populate(serviceCollection);
           containerBuilder.RegisterType<Service>().AsSelf();

           ....
}
```

I also needed to install some packages:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```